# Give write access to www-data and another user to a folder

Tags: linux, permissions, apache-http-server, ftp, chmod

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133024/www-data-permissions).

I have a custom logs folder at `public_html/logs/`

I need Apache (PHP scripts) to be able to write to that folder.

I also need FTP user `myuser` to able to read/write on that folder.

Doing the following command doesn't work: `chown -R myuser:www-data logs`

Note: `logs/` is currently have `755` permission.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

For those who care, this appears to be a simple permission mistake. All that's needed is to set permission to `775` instead of `755`.